# Play system sounds using system sound scheme (cross platform) with Qt

Tags: qt, audio, cross-platform

I'd like to play system sound for error in my Qt application. I understand not all systems have sound scheme, but the major ones do, and those are the ones I target at the moment.

So, can access some limited but cross-platform sound scheme?